# Issue when installing the Spacy python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I tried to install the **Spacy** package using the **conda terminal** with the command:
"conda install -c conda-forge spacy"
Even though the installation seems to be working, when I use Jupyter Notebook and *import spacy* I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-76a01d9c502b> in <module>
----> 1 import spacy

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py in <module>
      9 
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
---> 11 from thinc.api import prefer_gpu, require_gpu, require_cpu  # noqa: F401
     12 from thinc.api import Config
     13 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py in <module>
      3 
      4 from .about import __version__
----> 5 from .config import registry

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\thinc\config.py in <module>
     11 from pydantic.main import ModelMetaclass
     12 from pydantic.fields import ModelField
---> 13 from wasabi import table
     14 import srsly
     15 import catalogue

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\__init__.py in <module>
     10 from .about import __version__  # noqa
     11 
---> 12 msg = Printer()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\printer.py in __init__(self, pretty, no_print, colors, icons, line_max, animation, animation_ascii, hide_animation, ignore_warnings, env_prefix, timestamp)
     54         self.pretty = pretty and not env_no_pretty
     55         self.no_print = no_print
---> 56         self.show_color = supports_ansi() and not env_log_friendly
     57         self.hide_animation = hide_animation or env_log_friendly
     58         self.ignore_warnings = ignore_warnings

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\util.py in supports_ansi()
    262         if "ANSICON" in os.environ:
    263             return True
--> 264         return _windows_console_supports_ansi()
    265 
    266     return True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wasabi\util.py in _windows_console_supports_ansi()
    234             raise ctypes.WinError()
    235 
--> 236     console = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(sys.stdout.fileno())
    237     try:
    238         # Try to enable ANSI output support

UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```